# Get count or sum of values in dataframe of each day

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, sentiment-analysis

how to calculate the sum of the values ​​(1) and the sum of the values ​​(0) contained in each date?

or

how to calculate the sum of the values ​​(1) divided by the sum of the values ​​(0) in each date.

`sentiment_value = log10(count_of_(1)/count_of_(0))`, this is the formula I am using for.

```
date    new_sentiment
0   2017-04-28  1.0
1   2017-04-28  1.0
2   2017-04-28  1.0
3   2017-04-27  0.0
4   2017-04-27  1.0
5   2017-04-26  0.0
6   2017-04-26  1.0
7   2017-04-26  1.0
8   2017-04-26  0.0
9   2017-04-26  1.0

result_neg = date_df.appl
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please copy paste the content of image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
g = data.groupby(['date', 'new_sentiment']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()
g['sentiment_value'] = np.log((g[1.0])/(g[0.0]))
```

Output:

```
new_sentiment   date    0.0 1.0 sentiment_value
0            2017-04-26 2   3   0.405465
1            2017-04-27 1   1   0.000000
2            2017-04-28 0   3   inf
```

Comment: why with the inf value ?

Comment: @MuhFadlizi That is because for `2017-04-28`, there are no '0's. Hence `log(0)` becomes undefined. or `inf`